# Windows is off when run gulp watch

Tags: node.js, terminal, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-autoprefixer

**Hi There**

I'm working on a project which I'm using **Gulp** . All was Okay before i used **Autoprefixer** Plugin and **Watch** Command . Now when I run **gulp** at the terminal. My windows 10 is off without any **Error**  message .

**gulpfile.js code**

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    image_minify = require("gulp-image"),
    plumber = require("gulp-plumber"),
    autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");

/* Image Minify */
gulp.task("imageMinify", function() {
    gulp.src("assets/images/**/*")
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(image_minify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("assets/images/mini"));
});

/* Css Autoprefixer */
gulp.task("prefix", function() {
    gulp.src("assets/css/*.css")
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(autoprefixer({ browsers: ["last 10 versions"] }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("assets/style.css"));
});

/* Watch Function (watch the src and make action) */
gulp.task("watch", function() {
    gulp.watch("assets/images/**/*", ["imageMinify"]);
    gulp.watch("assets/css/*.css", ["prefix"]);

}); 
/* Default Function */
gulp.task("default", ["watch", "imageMinify", "prefix"]);
```

**Package.json Code**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-image": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "~3.3.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0"
  }
```

Any Help Please ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: are you saying... windows 10 shuts down when you run gulp?

Comment: @KevinB yes ... without any error or warning

Comment: Do you get any error or message when windows 10 comes back on?

Comment: @akinjide No :( .... Nothing

Comment: it shuts down suddenly and it works normally when i run it again .. Then when i run gulp watch it shuts down suddenly  again !!!

Comment: What version of Node and Gulp do you have installed?

Comment: What is " mini project " ?do you mean minify the project files ?
 i'm just beginner at gulp :)

Comment: Gulp :3.9.1 and Node : v6.11.2

Comment: to me this sounds like a problem unrelated to gulp, but i'm not sure what to suggest to try to narrow down what causes it. Try monitoring your hardware usage/temps before and during.

Comment: Adding to what kelvin said you can also create another mini project with Gulp and here's a sample gulpfile doing exactly what you're doing but in es6 >> https://github.com/akinjide/akinjide-photography/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Comment: @KevinB i thought that but i checked before it shuts down and it was normal ( CPU :12% , Memory: 86% , Disk : 58%) .Did it relate to the Memory ?

Comment: @akinjide Thanks will do that ,, hope this fix the problem

Comment: doubt it. but there's very few things that can cause an OS to flat out shut down unexpectedly, overheating being one of them

Comment: @KevinB For overheating,Yes i doubted it also and i watched .Once i run the window and first thing is run  "gulp watch" .. it shuts down .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a **performance** issue

My windows was **V 10** and Ram was **4**

The **solution** that worked for me was exchange the window version from 10 to 7 ultimate and it works well

Another good solution that change Ram with 8 or higher
But I preferred the first one as I wasn't comfortable with windows 10 performance :)